# Gui.Window won't show in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have some code like follwing:

```
if( GUI.Button(
  new Rect(Screen.width/4f,50f,Screen.width/2f,Screen.height/9f),"RessetLevel")) {

    showingWinsows = true;
    if(showingWinsows)
    {
      rectWindow = GUI.Window(
        0,
        rectWindow,
        DoMyWindow,
        "Are you sure you want to reset All level ?"
      );
    }
```

I've insert the `userGuiLayout = false;` in my `Awake()` function. But the window still doesn't show. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the window is only drawn when the button is pressed.

You need to move the code that checks the flag out of the if( GUI.Button ), something like this:

```
if( GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/4f,50f,Screen.width/2f,Screen.height/9f),"Resset Level"))
{ 
 showingWinsows = true;
}

if(showingWinsows)
{
  rectWindow = GUI.Window(0,rectWindow,DoMyWindow,"Are you sure you want to reset All level ?");
}
```